# Using subprocess.call to zip files in python

Tags: python, zip

I have a little problem with my server.

So the story:
I have a NAS what handles the e-mails of my domain. It works well, but it does not provide any backup software just for the e-mails, however it contains the mailboxes a little bit weirdly.

It contains them in the home directories of the users like "/home/user123/.Mailbox"

So if I want to collect these mailboxes and archive them I must code a little.

The problem is that although there is a kind of Linux on it, but it does not have bash but sh what does not have for loops.

On the other hand it has python module and I started to write a little script in it, but then I stuck...

When I wanted to use ZIP to package and compress the files I noticed it cannot handle the spaces between the parameters of the zip command if I pass them through a variable.

Can anyone offer me a solution for this?

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
from os import walk,path
import subprocess
import datetime

sourcepath="/home/"
savepath="/backups"
foldername=[]
tarparams=''
dt=str(datetime.date.today())

## get to know the directories in /home    
for (dirpath,dirnames,filenames) in walk(sourcepath):
    foldername.extend(dirnames)
    break
##

## check if the save path exists and if it does create the parameters of the compression
if not path.exists(savepath):
    print "Save path does not exist"
    exit()
else:
    for userhomedir in foldername:
        if path.exists(sourcepath+userhomedir+"/.Maildir"):
#           tarparams=tarparams+'"'+sourcepath+userhomedir+"/.Maildir"+'",'
            tarparams=tarparams+sourcepath+userhomedir+"/.Maildir "
        else:
        None
##

## call the zip command and compress the mailboxes with the highest compression
#subprocess.call(["zip","-r","-9",savepath+"/mailbkp-"+dt,tarparams])
subprocess.call(["zip","-r","-9",savepath+"/mailbkp-"+dt]+tarparams.split())
##
```

Thank you in advance. :-)

Comment: `["zip","-r","-9",savepath+"/mailbkp-"+dt]+tarparams.split()`?

Comment: you might want to look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html, will make the task easier

Comment: Are you sure posix shell doesn't have for loop ? If not, you can use while with `|`and `read`.

Comment: it looks like you re-save everything for each backup (hopefully to a different physical drive). In that case, consider rsync instead.

Comment: With laike9m's idea it works well. Many thanks to all of you guys! :-) Yes it will be saved to an external hdd each week.